# Android Developer Crashing on startActivity()

Tags: android

Hey everyone why does my app crash on start activity? I have a timer and when the timer runs out it is going to switch layouts and classes...

```
   public void onFinish() {
        setContentView(R.layout.high_score);
       Intent i = new Intent(start_menu.this, high_score.class);
        startActivity(i);
 }



    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView scoreTxt =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    int exScore = savedInstanceState.getInt("score");
    savedInstanceState.putInt("score", exScore);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    scoreTxt.setText("Score: "+exScore);



}
```

MY LOGCATS IN THE LINK :
       https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZL7v.png

Comment: did u check the value int exScore = savedInstanceState.getInt("score"); ?

Comment: print this value in logcat exScore.... and check it out ...if its null or not !

Answer (score 0):

You should post the logcat output..
BTW,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, high_score.class);
```

See: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html